# SAP Business Object 4.1 webi report slowness on https

Tags: redirect, https, business-objects

I am new to BO installation.
We have installed SBOP BI PLATFORM 4.1 SP05 SERVER WINDOWS server and for some webi report
which has longer query its giving slowness and hanging issue for more than one hour on HTTPS.
We ran IIS without HTTPS (on port 80) and there wasn’t any issue with
the timeouts and slowness. When we switch to HTTPS (on port 443), 
we were experiencing the issue.
 Configuration of both ports is the same, both ports are communicating with 
tomcat on same port with HTTP. This points out that issue is really in HTTPS.
I am wondering if there is an issue with BO application for timeout refresh hardcoded with http?
We have faced the slowness and hanging issues even when we redirect it through apache webserver.
HTTP works fine.Anysuggestion is welcome.
Thanks,
J

Comment: You'll need to provide us with more information regarding your setup. Is everything running on a single server? Are you running the Tomcat included with the BOBJ install or did you configure your own Tomcat? How is Tomcat configured? How did you configure the certificate for SSL? What else is running on the server (IIS, … )? In short, fully detail your setup.

Comment: Are you experiencing the *hanging* when refreshing a report or all throughout the interface? In other words, do you experience the issue when navigating through the Launchpad interface as well? Just to narrow down the scope.

Answer (score 1):

**Additional questions:**

- When/where are you experiencing the delay? With each action (logging on, navigating the web interface, …) or just with specific actions (e.g. refreshing a document). In the latter case, try with different documents to see if it is document specific or not.
- Are you experiencing the issue with both the BI Launchpad and the CMC?
- If you're using Web Intelligence, do you use the HTML or Java web interface? Do you see a difference when using either (i.e. does it work in HTML but not in Java)?
- If the delay is solely while refreshing a document, check if the query is actually running on the database when running through HTTPS. Also check if there is a difference in the generated query when running in HTTP and HTTPS.

**Suggestions:**

- Use a web debugging tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to compare the HTTP to the HTTPS connection. This might allow you to pinpoint why your connection slower using HTTPS.
- Test with different browsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome) to see if there's a difference.

**Remark:**

- If you're having issues with the HTTPS connection when using Tomcat, there's no point in adding a HTTP server in front of it.